# Installing debian on a Thecus 5500 DOM

Tags: debian, raid, software-raid

We recently purchased a [Thecus 5500](http://www.thecus.com/product.php?PROD_ID=22) NAS. Its DOM (~1Gb) is formatted with a custom Linux kernel. I have also purchased 5 HDDs, 1TB each which are to run as a RAID6 unit. Now I want to format the DOM with Debian and I want to have the RAID6 as the main filesystem, "/".

Should I have it installed exclusively on the DOM? Should I have a boot partition in both the DOM and all the RAID disks?

How can I achieve this when installing Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to install the Debian OS (version 8 or 9) exclusively on the 1gb DOM fails even for the netinstall version due to insufficient space on that disk.

Finally I made it work with the following configuration:

- **/boot -> on the DOM**
- / -> on a RAID6 over the HDDs (500Gb in total, 150 for each HDD)
- /data -> on another RAID6 over the HDDs (2.5Gb in total)

  - used for files, music, photos etc.
- Swap on a RAID1 over the HDDs

Finally, I don't know whether it's necessary with modern h/w but I had the "Bootable" flag turned ON  in the /boot partition.